# set row data in textfields

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have fetched data from selected row of a table in swing now I need to set those data in different text fields.

I have added mouse listener.

```
m_tblHistory.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            onSelectedRow();
            super.mouseClicked(e);
        }
    });
```

method onSelectedRow();

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
protected void onSelectedRow() {
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) m_tblHistory.getModel();

    int intRow = m_tblHistory.getSelectedRow();
    int intColumn = m_tblHistory.getColumnCount();

    Vector vecRow = new Vector();
    for (int i = 0; i < intColumn; i++) {
        vecRow.add(model.getValueAt(intRow, i));
        System.out.println("aaaaa = " + m_tblHistory.getModel().getColumnName(i));
    }

    onSetData(vecRow);
}
```

Now in onSetData method I need to set data to different textfields. One way is I can hard code it to get data corresponding to individual id or is there any other way to do this or is there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *I have added mouse listener.*

[MouseListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html) is not the right choice to listen to selection changes. You should attach a [ListSelectionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/event/ListSelectionListener.html) to the table's  [ListSelectionModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/ListSelectionModel.html) if you want to listen for rows selection changes:

```
JTable table = new JTable();
table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
     @Override
     public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
         // your code here
     }
 });
```

See more in [Users Selections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#selection) section of [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) tutorial.

> *One way is I can hard code it to get data corresponding to individual id or is there any other way to do this or is there?*

Yes there is another better and more elegant way: implement your own [TableModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html). You can use [AbstractTableModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html) as base. See [Creating a Table Model](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data)

Comment: thanks, ListSelectionListener also worked, I am facing new problem after refreshing the table that is clearing the data and adding new rows, it throws ArrayIndexOutOfBound Exception. How to overcome this issue?

PS : if I use MouseAdapter event this works perfectly.

Comment: You are welcome :) It sounds like you are attempting to access an invalid row/column index in your code, for some reason. Please consider ask a new question with your code and most important the [full stack trace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors). @Akshat